# Swift shrink UIImageView according to what image it contains

Tags: swift, imageview

I have an UIImageView which is as big as the whole view. When I insert an image, I would like for the image view to shrink itself in order for it to be as big as the image I insert itself. I cannot find a way to do it.

Comment: Do you want an image view size should be change when image size is smaller or larger ? Like as, Initially imageView size is 200x200 and image size is 100x100, then imageView size should changes to 100x100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can approach this assuming you have a `UIImageView` declared like so:

```
  @IBOutlet var dynamicImageView: UIImageView!
```

1. When changing your image, set the imageView size to that of the `UIImage` e.g:

   ```
   func changeImage(){

       if let image = UIImage(named: "Octocat"){
           dynamicImageView.image = image
           dynamicImageView.frame.size = image.size
           print("Size Of ImageView = \(dynamicImageView.frame.size)")

       }
   }
   ```
2. Just use the `.sizeToFit` method e.g:

   ```
   func changeImageAgain(){

       if let image = UIImage(named: "Octocat"){
           dynamicImageView.image = image
           dynamicImageView.sizeToFit()
           print("Size Of ImageView = \(dynamicImageView.frame.size)")

       }
   }
   ```

Running on an iPhone 7 Plus the `UIImageView` size is initially (375,647), and when applying either method the size changes to (800,665) which is the same size as the `GitHub OctoCat`:

[image]

Comment: My image view is created programmatically but there is no difference I guess right?

Comment: Of course not just use either  dynamicImageView.frame.size = image.size or  dynamicImageView.sizeToFit() ^______^.

Answer (score 0):

I have created one demo app which will contains XIB with image view. Here I have written code to resize imageView as per image size. This code is working in my project, I shared link for demo app, you can download and test it.

In this project, I have implemented code to create imageView based on image size and vertically and horizontally centred aligned.

Also implemented code to zoom image.

https://app.box.com/s/sro2g7gdv5c67f9oj97gfhicjnpo2vqc

I hope this will work for you and as per your requirement.

Comment: It's great your posting a full project, but it might be worth explaining how to solve the problem so others can learn ^________^.